# How to print directory contents on remote server to txt file, SSH?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Logged into a remote server with SSH, If I'm in a subdirectory with 50K images, how can I print this directory content (not absolute path ideally) into a txt file in the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

if I understood rigth you want to print only the file names inside the directory onto a file under the same directory.

That can be accomplished with the following command executed inside the subdirectory:

`ls > list_of_files.log`